# Troubles accessing the VirtualHost on a local net

Tags: linux, apache, dns, asterisk, virtualhost

Hi I have a Huawei ADSL modem with a dynamic IP. I set up a dynamic dns with freedns and I can easily access my Virtual host on apache from outside my private network, from internet.

So trying to access it from a local network I get a modems login page.

I have the rule in my modems NAT to connect port 80 to my server but it seems it doesnt work from internal net.

My server hosting the virtual host is 192.168.0.1 , the modem has the 192.168.0.254 address.

I tried to put my external domain name into the /etc/hosts file, but if I do that then asterisk server gets confused.

What could be the cause of the problem ? And what would be the best solution to this problem ?

Should I set up a caching DNS on the private side of the net ?

Answer (score 1):

Hugger is half right... Its because your router is blocking loopbacks. The easiest way around this is to edit the hosts file [(See the Wiki page)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) on the computer that is behind the network to see the local IP of the computer as the virtual host your going for. For example if your server is on 192.168.0.1 and the virtual hostname is www.imrad.com then insert 

`192.168.0.1 www.imrad.com`

into your hosts file. If your computer leaves the local network (like a laptop you take to work) and joins a network not behind your router you need to comment out the line in the hosts file.

Comment: Ok, thanks, one solution is to alter the host file on each machine we have in the office. But I thought maybe its easier to put up a local only caching dns and make dhcp configure the machines to use that dns. What you think ?

Answer (score 0):

well actually to access that you must find the local ip address of the server by going into command line/prompt and typing ipconfig /all then you will find ipv4 address. Take note of that. 
Go to another computer and your that ip and it will show.

The reason that was happening is because the router/modem knows you are in its network so it will think you ar trying to go top the login page of it. That happens to me too.

Comment: I know the server internal ip , but accessing that it does not show me the desired web page, because i have a virtual host running on that machine. 

So what is strange to me is that when i put that in the linux laptop /etc/hosts file it still showed up the routers login page, and not the virtual host i would like to access.